# Remove select all checkbox in PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

Is there a way to remove the select all check box on the header of  the `p:datatable`.

I need check box on the individual row but not on the header.

Answer (score 9):

This works very well :

```
.ui-chkbox.ui-chkbox-all.ui-widget {
    display:none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is below:

Add the below in your default.css file:

```
.table-no-select-all .ui-chkbox-all {
     display: none !important;
}
```

And then in your facelet, refer that like below:

```
<h:form id="form"> 
   <p:dataTable id="cars" rowIndexVar="idx" styleClass="table-no-select-all" ...>
     <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />  
   </p:dataTable>
 </h:form>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do this by using p:columnGroup for specifying headers.

```
 <p:dataTable id="selectByPotentialTable" var="replacementByPotential"
    widgetVar="selectByPotentialTable"
    value="#{kmSelectByPotentialBean.allReplacementPrintersViewModel}"
    selection="#{kmSelectByPotentialBean.selectedByPotentialReplacement}">

        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
               <p:column/>
               <p:column headerText="Printer Model"/>
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%;text-align:center"/>
        <p:column>
            #{replacementByPotential.name}
        </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

If you change your mind and you want the selectAll checkbox to be displayed, you need to change

```
<p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
        <p:column/>
           <p:column headerText="Printer Model"/>
        </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

to

```
<p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
           <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%;text-align:center"/>
           <p:column headerText="Printer Model"/>
        </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in PrimeFaces 6.0

```css
.ui-widget-header div.ui-chkbox.ui-widget {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<h:form id="form"> 
   <p:dataTable id="cars" rowIndexVar="idx" ...>
     <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />  
   </p:dataTable>
 </h:form>
```

Primefaces add default suffix `_head` to datatable's header, in example: datatable's header will have id cars_head, so you can disable `select all checkbox` via css
`.ui-chkbox-box.ui-widget.ui-corner-all.ui-state-default` is checkbox's style of all checkbox in datatable.

If you use `JSF 2.0`:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #form-cars_head .ui-chkbox-box.ui-widget.ui-corner-all.ui-state-default{
            display:none !important;
        }
    </style>
```

you need to add this configuration to `web.xml` to use '-' in component's id:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
        <param-value>-</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: I was able to achieve this by overriding .ui-chkbox-all{ display: none !important;} but this is applied to all the all the tables. Is there a way it can be applied to one particular table.

Answer (score 0):

In PrimeFaces 8.

```css
.ui-datatable .ui-selection-column .ui-chkbox-all {
    display: none !important;
}
```